# Find total amount of disk space used by a Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I am looking for a way to get the total amount of disk space used by a
Elasticsearch cluster. I have found suggestions to use the following REST API endpoints to obtain this information among other things:

```
GET /_cat/stats
GET /_nodes/stats
```

I was wondering can the same information be obtained using the Elasticsearch Java High-Level REST Client or the Transport Client in an older version of Elasticsearch?

Comment: There is no specific method to get node stats from high level client. You just need to call ```/_nodes/stats``` directly from your code

Comment: @SankarPrasanthGadhamsetti I already provided this info in my answer also added a working code sample to achieve that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that disk stats can be obtained using the `_nodes/stats` API as  REST high-level client doesn't provide any direct API for node stats, you can see all the API supported by it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html).

But you can use the low level rest client which is provide in high level client and below is the working example code.

```
 private void getDiskStats(RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) throws IOException {
        RestClient lowLevelClient = restHighLevelClient.getLowLevelClient();
        Request request = new Request(
                "GET",
                "/_nodes/stats");
        Response response = lowLevelClient.performRequest(request);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println("resp: \n"+ EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }
    }
```

You can see I am printing the O/P of above API on console and verified that it contains the disk usage status which comes in below format:

```
"most_usage_estimate": {
"path": "/home/opster/runtime/elastic/elasticsearch-7.8.1/data/nodes/0",
"total_in_bytes": 124959473664,
"available_in_bytes": 6933352448,
"used_disk_percent": 94.45151916481107
},
```